# c# Сокеты, сообщения между сокетами

Tags: c#, сервер, сокет

У меня есть сервер к которому коннектится клиент, на сервере обрабатываются какие-либо запросы от клиентов, при коннекте клиента обработка идет в отдельном потоке. Нужно как-то реализовать связь между подключенными клиентами.

Сделать так: первый клиент отправляет сообщение и индификатор второго клиента => сообщение обрабатывается сервером => по id или другому индификатору сообщение отправлялось ко второму клиенту => второй клиент получает сообщение.

Comment: В чем именно у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: 1) Как мне узнать какие сокеты подключены? 2) Как по id отправить им какое-либо сообщение?

Comment: Создайте коллекцию где вы будете хранить, id  подключившихся клиентов и ассоциированные с ними данные такие как сокеты и т д, когда клиент отправляет сообщение идите в коллекцию и смотрите есть такой клиент или нет, если есть то все остальное дело техники.

Comment: Не могли бы привести пример коллекции? И еще пример отправки сокету из колеекции сообщения?

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary<int, System.Net.Sockets.Socket> ConectedClients` коллекция где `int` это Id клиента, отправка тривиальна, получаете из коллекции сокет клиента по Id `ConectedClients.TryGetValue(clientId, out var clientSocket)` после чего используете стандартный метод сокета  `clientSocket.Send("Данные от клиента к клиенту")`. Понятное дело что надо будет учесть еще сотню нюансов и не факт что мой пример именно то что вам надо, но я думаю в процессе написания вы сможете всё понять или сможете сформулировать новые более конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо!  попробую

Comment: Ваш способ помог! Не могли бы вы написать в ответ для того, чтобы я пометил его как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConcurrentDictionary<int, System.Net.Sockets.Socket> ConectedClients` коллекция где `int` это `Id` клиента, отправка тривиальна, получаете из коллекции сокет клиента по `Id` `ConectedClients.TryGetValue(clientId, out var clientSocket)` после чего используете стандартный метод сокета `clientSocket.Send("Данные от клиента к клиенту")`.

Понятное дело что надо будет учесть еще сотню нюансов и не факт что мой пример именно то что вам надо, но я думаю в процессе написания вы сможете всё понять или сможете сформулировать новые более конкретные вопросы.